# YouCompleteMe unavailable: unable to load Python

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows, vimscript-python, error, version

I have done `PlugInstall` but it gives:

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: unable to load  Python.
```

The same error happens while loading UltiSnips:

```
E370: Could not load python36.dll
```

My vimrc:

```
set rnu
set nu
set autoindent
set noerrorbells
set colorcolumn=80
set tabstop=2
set bg=light
colorscheme elflord
set guifont=Courier:h14
set spelllang=en,en_us
set spell
call plug#begin()
Plug 'junegunn/vim-plug'
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'SirVer/UltiSnips'
call plug#end()
let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
```

[image]

which contains python.

After looking at  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278560/python-interpreter-shell-with-vim-integration-possible#:~:text=to%20get%20a%20python%20shell%20directly%20in%20vim.&text=From%20a%20new%20Vim%20screen,%2C%20press%20m%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278560/python-interpreter-shell-with-vim-integration-possible#:%7E:text=to%20get%20a%20python%20shell%20directly%20in%20vim.&text=From%20a%20new%20Vim%20screen,%2C%20press%20m%20). I installed the ConqueShell plugin and did `:ConqueTerm python`

```
Conque ERROR: Python interface cannot be loaded

Your version of Vim appears to be installed without the Python interface.

You appear to be using Windows. The official Vim 7.3 installer available at 
http://www.vim.org comes with the required Python interfaces. You will also 
need to install Python 2.7 and/or Python 3.1, both available at http://www.python.org
```

`:echo has('python3')` returns 0

I added: `let &pythonthreedll = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\python3complete'` to my vimrc but the problem persists

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble How to copy and paste vim version (every time I press a key it first goes to —More— then completely erases it

Comment: you could use redirect, or the mouse?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble may I link to that blogpost as a response to screenshots of text elsewhere on stackexchange?

Comment: @guntbert by all means! I wrote it in part for that purpose :) and it has links (i think) to other relevant [meta.so] and [meta.se] posts

Comment: Looks like you have a 32-bit Vim... Do you have a 32-bit Python to match that? You can tell by looking at `sys.maxsize` from your Python interpreter, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1405913/9447571

Comment: I believe `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\python3complete'` should be what goes into `&pythonthreehome`, the `&pythonthreedll` option should be set to the `python36.dll` (or whatever the `python*.dll` file is called) inside your Python 3 installation. You can check that Python 3 is working on Vim with `:py3 print('hello')` which will only work if it's properly configured.

Comment: @filbranden ````:py3 ...```` returns ````Sorry this command is disabled. Could not load python library```` . How do I make sure ````python3complete```` goes into ````&pythonthreehome```` and the ````&pythonthreedll```` is set to ````python36.dll````

Comment: Try setting `&pythonthree` to the *full path* to the library! Can you find it? It will have the `*.dll` extension... Does that help then?

Comment: @filbranden I'm sorry but I have no idea what ````&pythonthree,full path,*.dll extension```` mean

Comment: Look at the `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\python3complete'` directory you mentioned and search for a file with a `DLL` extension under it. It will probably be in a `Lib` subdirectory and the name might be something like `python36.dll` or similar. Then adjust your `let &pythonthreedll` to list the full name to that file. For example, `let &pythonthreedll = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\python3complete\Lib\python36.dll'` but of course use the correct names of the subdirectory and file you found, my example is probably incorrect since I don't know your exact setup.

Comment: @filbranden I went to ````C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\autoload````  and into ````pythonthreecomplete.vim````and I tried searching ````/&pythonthreedll```` but it had no result (pattern not found).

Comment: Follow the instructions in the duplicate answer to configure Python for Vim on Windows.

Comment: @filbranden  how do I check what bit vim and python is being used?

Comment: Vim will show it under `:version` (from your screenshot, yours is `MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version`.)

Comment: For Python, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1405913/9447571

Comment: @fibranden I don't know how to use powershell is there another way to check